# Multi-line text to CSV using AWK

Tags: csv, awk, gawk

I have a file like this:

```
// question: 0  name: Switch category to $cat1$/Pretest Durchführung MIT 04//05/IKT_1_PT/IKT_1_PT_2_MIT05
$CATEGORY: $cat1$/Pretest Durchführung MIT 04//05/IKT_1_PT/IKT_1_PT_2_MIT05


// question: 164887  name: PT_IKT_1_01_ FTP
::PT_IKT_1_01_ FTP::Wozu dient das FTP Protokoll?{
    ~%-100%Blah1
    ~%-100%Blah2
    =Blah3
    ~%-100%Blhah4.
}


// question: 164888  name: PT_IKT_1_02_Verteilte_Systeme
::PT_IKT_1_02_Verteilte_Systeme::Question2?{
    ~%-100%A1
    ~%-100%A2
    =A3
    ~%-100%A4
}

// question: 164893  name: PT_IKT_1_07_Rational_Unified_Process
::PT_IKT_1_07_Rational_Unified_Process::Question3?{
    ~%-50%A1
    ~%-50%A2
    ~%50%A3
    ~%50%A4
}
```

How can I create output like this using AWK?

```
PT_IKT_1_01_ FTP;Wozu dient das FTP Protokoll?;Blah1;F;Blah2;F;Blah3;T;Blhah4.;F
PT_IKT_1_02_Verteilte_Systeme;Question2?;A1;F;A2;F;A3;T;A4;F
PT_IKT_1_07_Rational_Unified_Process;Question3?;A1;F;A2;F;A3;T;A4;T
```

So - in front of answer text  indicates a wrong answer, and = indicates the answer is true.However, there are lines where only one answer is true in which case there are no numbers indicating how many percent of answers are either true or false.

The Input file is a subset of the GIFT file format specification at https://docs.moodle.org/23/en/GIFT_format

Comment: Why don't you use a GIFT parser? Like this: https://github.com/stuart/gift-parser

Answer (score 1):

You can do some like this:

```
awk -v RS="" -F"\n" '$2~/^::/ {sub(/::/,"",$2);sub(/::/,";",$2);sub(/{/,"",$2);for(i=3;i<=6;i++) {n=split($i,a,"[%=]");m=m";"a[n]";"(i==5?"T":"F")};print $2 m;m=""}' file
PT_IKT_1_01_ FTP;Wozu dient das FTP Protokoll?;Blah1;F;Blah2;F;Blah3;T;Blhah4.;F
PT_IKT_1_02_Verteilte_Systeme;Question2?;A1;F;A2;F;A3;T;A4;F
PT_IKT_1_07_Rational_Unified_Process;Question3?;A1;F;A2;F;A3;T;A4;F
```

PS, I am not sure how you get those `F` and  `T`.  I did assume `F;F;T;F` but you have one `F;F;T;T`

Some more readable:

```
awk -v RS="" -F"\n" '
$2~/^::/ {
    sub(/::/,"",$2)
    sub(/::/,";",$2)
    sub(/{/,"",$2)
        for(i=3;i<=6;i++) {
            n=split($i,a,"[%=]")
            m=m";"a[n]";"(i==5?"T":"F")}
        print $2 m;m=""
    }
' file
```

Comment: `NF-1` might be better than `6` here. Also I think that T/F decision wants to be something like `$i ~ /^=/ || a[2] !~ /^-/`.

Comment: @EtanReisner, i do agree that it may be a good idea to change to `NF-1`, since it then will cover unlimited fields, if it that OP wants.

Comment: @EtanReisner no, the sample is correct. = is a correct answer, - denotes a wrong answer. So in the last sample there are two correct answers. Anyhow, the suggestion is brittle. I am not very fluent in (g)awk, but wouldn't a solution using eg RS="//" be better?

Comment: @JohnDoe According to the linked docs both a leading `=` and a lack of a `-` are correct answers with the latter being partial credit. That's also what your T/F markers in your sample output map to. As written, this doesn't generate that. And a null `RS` means to split on blank lines.